# Permission denied (publickey). IN GITHUB

Tags: git, github

I followed the ways given by GitHub help website.
And already added my pub key to GitHub settings.
I'm sure that I copy the pub key correct.
But I got the response that the permission denied.
Moreover, I can join my friend's Repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you also set your GitHub token

http://help.github.com/set-your-user-name-email-and-github-token/

Comment: Do you know for a fact this ssh key is valid?  Have you used to ssh to another machine?

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons for this, I would probably just check for this first

```
ssh -vT git@github.com
```

Analyze the output to see what comes up

Source: http://help.github.com/ssh-issues/

Answer (score 0):

May be this problem occurred when you tried accessing your github account using a new system mostly MacOS. To do the authentication that you are accessing the correct server the your OS uses ssh protocol to communicate to the github server. For that the ssh key generated by your OS should be saved in the guthub.

Follow the steps given in official docs of github. The error occur mainly due to the absence of ssh agent key in your github. You need to generate one in your OS and then paste it in the ssh key setting option of github.

https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/error-permission-denied-publickey